# Message Centre Number, SMSC, ESME, SMPP

Tags: networking, mobile, network-protocols, smpp

I am about to work on SMPP. I have basic knowledge of how message from Computer system to mobile passes, i have read about how message passes from ESME to SMSC to Mobile Station. But I can't understand it practically. I mean, are these (ESME SMSC) any hardware implitations or softwares installed on Computer? I also want to know the role of Short message centre number in this process.
If possible please give any external material to refer in deep.

Answer (score 2):

ESME and SMSC both are application installed on some machines (servers), SMS Message Centre Number is a phone number that acts as a gateway for transferring SMS messages between cellular devices.

Answer (score 2):

The [SMPP 3.4 specification](http://docs.nimta.com/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) is invaluable in understanding what the components are, and how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider starting by reading SMPP specifications (link given by acraig5075). Also you may try going through how the SMSC system works by playing with an SMPP simulator. Try SMPPSim built by Selenium Software:

http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html